# A question related to the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Consider a complex sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined as follows:
$$a_0=0 \text{ and }a_n=\frac{1}{2i+a_{n-1}}, \text{ for }n\geq 1.$$

I am interested in showing whether this sequence converges or not.

**My attempt:** I made use of the fact that if a limit, say $L$, of the given sequence exists, then it must be that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n-1}=L$, which gives us the equation $L=\frac{1}{2i+L}\Longrightarrow L^2 +2iL-1=0 \Longrightarrow L=-i.$ Now if I can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n+i|=0$, then it follows that $a_n \to -i$. But I am kind of stuck on how to prove this claim.

Any help/hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is $i$? Is it a constant?

Comment: @A.P. It is the square root of $-1$.

Comment: I completely skipped the part "complex sequence", thank you for the questions @Mark. I got it. That was a lapsus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain each term in the series using mathematical induction. The form of the  equation with $a_0=0$ gives $a_n = -\lambda_n i$, where $\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Substituting a few terms the values in the series $\lambda_{n}$ are $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, ...$.

Assume $a_n = -i\frac{n}{n+1} $. This holds true for n=0, 1.

$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2i -\frac{in}{n+1}} = \frac{n+1}{i(n+2)}=-i\frac{n+1}{(n+2)}$

This completes the proof.

Comment: That's much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from @QC_QAOA nice approach
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{i\,b_n}{i+b_n}$$ let $c_n=\frac 1{b_n}$ to face
$$c_{n+1}=c_n+\frac 1i=c_n-i \implies c_n=-ni+C$$

$$c_n=-ni+C \implies b_n=\frac 1{C-ni}\implies a_n=\frac {1-n-i C}{C-ni} $$  Since $a_0=0$ then $C=-i$ and
$$a_n=-i\frac{ n}{n+1}$$